# Sorting strings alphabetically in C language

Tags: c, arrays, string, sorting, alphabetical-sort

I made a program that asks the user to enter a name if they select option 2 and it stores that name in the string, if the user selects option 3 then it will display that name. Now for option 4 it needs to alphabetize the names in order, so when i select option 3 again to view the names it would show them in alphabetical order. My friend told me to use strcpy(), and i attempted it but not too successfully.

This is my code:

```
//This is my code:

#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main() {

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    while (1) {
        int num;
        char name[500][100],t[100];
        printf("\nPress 1 to see author info\n");
        printf("Press 2 to enter a name\n");
        printf("Press 3 to view names\n");
        printf("Press 4 to alphabatize names\n");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        char arr[100];


        if (num == 1)
            {
                printf("----------------\n");
                printf("name\n");
                printf("132\n");
                printf("----------------\n");
            }   


        if (num == 2)
            {
                printf("Enter the name (no spaces)\n");
                scanf("%s", arr);
                strcpy(name[i], arr);
                i++;
            }
        if (num == 3)
            {
                printf("\n******************************");

                for (int j = 0; j<i; j++)
                    {
                        printf("\n%s\n", &name[j]);
                    }
                printf("\n\n\n******************************");
            }


        if (num == 4)
            {

                for (i = 1; i < j; i++) {
                    for (j = 1; j < i; j++) {
                        if (strcmp(name[j - 1], name[j]) > 0) {
                            strcpy(t, name[j - 1]);
                            strcpy(name[j - 1], name[j]);
                            strcpy(name[j], t);
                        }
                    }
                }

                ;
            }

        return(0)
            system("pause");
    }
```

Comment: You're missing a `}`. You have `return(0)` inside the loop, so it exits the program before giving you a chance to answer the question again. You're also missing `;` at the end of the `return(0)` line.

Comment: There's no problem with how you're using `strcpy()`. The problem is your loops. If `i` is the total number of names that have been entered, using it as the iteration variable in the `for` loop will destroy that. Use a different variable.

Comment: Are you required to write your own sorting code? If not, you could use the built-in `qsort()`.

Comment: Yeah i need to write my own sorting code, without using the bubble sort.

Answer (score 0):

If Barmar doesn't want to make the comment an answer:

As noted: the `i` you use in the outer loop is the total, you cannot use it, you need a fresh one, say `k`. Sorted alphabetically gives:

```
int k;
if (num == 4) {
  for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    for (k = 0; k < i - j - 1; k++) {
      if (strcmp(name[k], name[k + 1]) > 0) {
        strcpy(t, name[k]);
        strcpy(name[k], name[k+1]);
        strcpy(name[k+1], t);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I used a slightly different approach for the bubble sort, that's how I learned it, hope you can make sense of it.

Note: copying the full strings is not the best way to do it but I don't know if you already learned about pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Modified your code. It seems that for this situation, switch case would be prettier and that your loop will never end. With what @Barmar said, your loop has a `return 0;` therefore terminates prematurely. I have changed some elements of your codes too as some of them are suited to be undisturbed etc. etc.

## Change List

*Besides the implementation of switch case*

> 1. Name and position of char arrays. For t[100], since it is a temporary object/variable I moved it into `case (4)` (Refer to line 63
>      in the modified code) so that the creation happens on demand instead
>      of the original code where creation is made early. Renamed t to temp.
>      As for arr, I've renamed it so that it is clearer (nameIn to indicate
>      name Input)
> 2. Name of num. To make it easier to understand the code, I've set it to nameCount, to indicate the number of name, or the size.
> 3. Restructured loops so that their counters do not modifiy nameCount by any means and only use it as a mean of comparison.
> 4. Added exit condition for the loop to terminate, -1 as well as a default case should invalid input is provided. (Does not check for
>      alphabet input)

## Modified Code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    int nameCount = 0, num = 0;

    while (num != -1)
    {
        char nameIn[100];
        char name[100][100];

        printf("\nPress 1 to see author info\n");
        printf("Press 2 to enter a name\n");
        printf("Press 3 to view names\n");
        printf("Press 4 to alphabatize names\n");
        scanf("%d", &num);

        switch(num)
        {
            case (1):
                {
                    printf("----------------\n");
                    printf("name\n");
                    printf("132\n");
                    printf("----------------\n");

                    break;
                }
            case (2):
                {
                    printf("Enter the name (no spaces)\n");
                    scanf("%s", nameIn);
                    strcpy(name[nameCount], nameIn);
                    nameCount++;

                    break;
                }

            case (3):
                {
                    printf("\n******************************");

                    for (int ctr = 0; ctr<nameCount; ctr++)
                    {
                        printf("\n%s\n", &name[ctr]);
                    }
                    printf("\n\n\n******************************");

                    break;
                }
            case (4):
                {
                    for (int ctrLv1 = 0; ctrLv1 < nameCount-1; ctrLv1++)
                    {
                        printf("\nhere here");
                        for (int ctrLv2 = ctrLv1+1; ctrLv2 < nameCount; ctrLv2++)
                        {
                            printf("\nif fail?\n\n\n");
                            if (strcmp(name[ctrLv1], name[ctrLv2]) > 0)
                            {
                                char temp[100] = "";

                                strcpy(temp, name[ctrLv1]);
                                strcpy(name[ctrLv1], name[ctrLv2]);
                                strcpy(name[ctrLv2], temp);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    break;
                }
            case (-1):
                {
                    printf("\nExiting...\n");
                    break;
                }
            default:
                {
                    printf("Invalid input");
                    break;
                }
        }

    }

    return(0);
}
```